# How can i write javascript and html code for this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, css-transitions

[image]

I want to make a grid that contains alphabets (as shown in the fig above) and have a transition event like blinking. which continuously blinks with a certain period of time(like first a after b.. and so on again a) in a continuous loop and when I press enter it should output the letter where the blinking is using javascript and HTML
I have tried the code below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <style>
    .keys {
      display: flex;
    }
    
    .key {
      border: .4rem solid black;
      border-radius: .5rem;
      margin: 1rem;
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      padding: 1rem .5rem;
      width: 5rem;
      text-align: center;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      transition: all 0.07s ease;
    }
    
    .playing {
      transform: scale(1, 1);
      border-color: #ffc600;
      box-shadow: 0 0 1rem #ffc600;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="keys">
    <div class="key">A</div>
    <div class='key'>B</div>
    <div class='key'>C</div>
    <div class='key'>D</div>
    <div class='key'>E</div>
    <div class='key'>F</div>

  </div>
  <script>
    key.ClassList.add('playing');
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You tried the code and...what happened?

Comment: it's incomplete code. I couldn't understand the logic to make as I am a newbie in javascript.@RobertColumbia

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it something like this -

```js
let curr_div_on = 0,
  curr_div_off = 0;

// get the div on whose child we want to apply this effect
const key = document.getElementsByClassName("key");

// this function will toggle on the effect
function setPlayingOn() {
  key[curr_div_on % 6].classList.add("playing");
  curr_div_on = (curr_div_on + 1) % 6; // taking modulo to ensure index remains within bound and effect start from first once it reaches end
}
// this function will toggle off the effect
function setPlayingOff() {
  key[curr_div_off % 6].classList.remove("playing");
  curr_div_off = (curr_div_off + 1) % 6;
}
// setInterval will set to call the toggle on function every 500ms
setInterval(setPlayingOn, 500);
// setInterval will set to call the toggle on function every 500ms. But here setTimeout is used to delay the first call made to toggle_playing_off 
setTimeout(() => setInterval(setPlayingOff, 500), 500);

document.addEventListener("keypress", function() {
  console.log(curr_div_on);
});
```

```css
/* use display as flex and a fixed wdith so last 3 divs wrap off and go below as you wanted*/

#keys {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 30rem;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.key {
  border: 0.4rem solid black;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1rem 0.5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  transition: all 0.07s ease;
}

.playing {
  transform: scale(1, 1);
  border-color: #ffc600;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1rem #ffc600;
}
```

```html
<div id="keys">
  <div class="key">A</div>
  <div class='key'>B</div>
  <div class='key'>C</div>
  <div class='key'>D</div>
  <div class='key'>E</div>
  <div class='key'>F</div>
</div>
```

If you didn't know about the things I mentioned in the answer and didn't get a proper understanding through my comment explanation, you could know more about them here -

- [`setInterval()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)
- [`setTimeout()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)
- [`flexBox`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

Comment: Just a note: if I use the word "toggle", I write one function to toggle between states (2 or more, on/off or red/green/yellow/blue, etc.).  If I use two functions, like in your answer, I'd just call the functions`playing_on` and `playing_off`...

Comment: @iAmOren I had to toggle each div, wait some time interval and then toggle it back off. I figured, using two functions would be easier to understand the flow of how it works which is why I went with `add()` and `remove()` instead of `toggle()`

Comment: @harsh I have declared two variables at start, which hold the index of div to be toggled. In the functions, I am just taking the index and toggling it on or off respectively. The `%6` just ensures that we toggle div from `0 to 6`

Comment: I understand the use of two functions.  I am just pointing out that the use of "toggle" as part of a function name in more than one function is confusing - at least me... :)  I'm talking about the names of the functions which doesn't matter to the computer, but can confuse humans - at least me.  I'm not debating the functionality/code.  :)

Comment: @iAmOren Oh.. I thought you were talking about the method I used for toggling. ok, now I have changed the name. Maybe now its less confusing :)

Comment: if I want to console.log() the characters that are high lighted, when I press enter what are the changes should I need to make? @Abhiskek

Comment: Perfecter!  = More perfect(?)... :)

Comment: @harsh Check the edit. I have added the cod for `console.log()`

Comment: @harsh Did the answer help? If it did, you can mark it as accepted by checking the  green tick :)

Comment: it is printing letters continuously. I need an event listener which prints only when I press enter or any letter from the keyboard.@Abhishek

Comment: @harsh you just need to add an onkeypress eventlistener to whole doc

Comment: @harsh Check the edit I made. This should work as expected by you

Comment: @Abhishek i have a doubt. can you please look into it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63285169/how-to-use-getelementsbyclassname-for-adding-both-grids-and-display-one-after