# How to use getElementsByClassName() for adding both grids and display one after another?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, css-transitions

1. I Have Tried to add grid-2 when we press a key, but it's not working as I expected.
2. When it is displaying grid-2 I want the grid to disappear (I don't know how to do).

(background):-
I have searched and found there is a visibility property in CSS, but don't know how to apply to the whole grid and undo the visibility property and make them visible.

I have tried to add the grid-2 by getElementById but both the grids are appearing at a time.
(don't know how to make them appear one after another).

```js
let curr_div_on = 0,curr_div_off = 0;


const key = document.getElementsByClassName('keys');


function setPlayingOn() {
  key[curr_div_on % 4].classList.add("playing");
  curr_div_on = (curr_div_on + 1) % 4; 
}

function setPlayingOff() {
  key[curr_div_off % 4].classList.remove("playing");
  curr_div_off = (curr_div_off + 1) % 4;
}

setInterval(setPlayingOn, 500);
setTimeout(() => setInterval(setPlayingOff, 500), 500);

document.addEventListener('keypress', function(){
  if(curr_div_on ==1){
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName("grid-2");
    element.classList.add("grid");
      }
  
})
```

```css
.grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-gap:10px;
  
}

.key{
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  text-align:center;
}

.playing{
  transform: scale(1,1);
    border-color: #ffc600;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1rem #ffc600;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <div class='grid'>
    <div class='key'>ABCD</div>
    <div class='key'>EFGH</div>
    <div class='key'>IJKL</div>
    <div class='key'>LMNO</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class='grid-2'>
    <div class='button'>A</div>
    <div class='button'>B</div>
    <div class='button'>C</div>
    <div class='button'>D</div>
  </div>
</html>
```

Comment: There are no `id="..."` attributes in your HTML, so how would you expect `getElementById()` to work??

Comment: Thanks, for showing my mistake but it's still not working @NiettheDarkAbsol

Answer (score 0):

I think the code is wrong in these two points:

- const key = document.getElementsByClassName('keys'); --> The selector should be 'key'
- var element = document.getElementsByClassName("grid-2"); --> The result is a list (DomTokenList), so you should take the first element (var element = document.getElementsByClassName("grid-2")[0];)